# How to pass generic list of values to external js file from controller/view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The file name is called `clik.js` here I have to access some values from controller/view

Using view I have tried this code:

```
<head>
    @if (ViewBag.status != null)
    {
       
    <script type="text/javascript">

                var tagAccess='@ViewBag.status[0]';
    </script>
     <script src="~/JavaScript/click.js"></script>

    }
</head>
```

Using this code, I could get single value in js file. But I have to get all values

```
//var tagAccess='@ViewBag.status';
```

If I write the code like this, I didn't get any output

Comment: can you use a view model?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the Item using this:

```
<script>
  var tagAccess = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.status[0]));
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your response. when i use serialize i got some json error. so i used  var tagAccess=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.status)); this one i got the output.

Comment: @Kavi Check the updated answer, you should be able to serialize anything with the code. What is the content of @ViewBag.status[0]?